# Rails, pass a path variable to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I 'm building a partial that will be use by different views (games and promotions).
I've created a partial in view/application

```
<%= content_tag :article, class: ['article'] do %>
  <a href="#">
    <%= image_tag item.thumbnail %>
  </a>
  <h2><%= item.name %></h2>
  <p><%= item.description %></p>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Read more', "#" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and I call it from the view games view (or promotions):

```
<% @games.each do |item| %>
  <section> 
      <%= render 'application/item_synopsis_builder', item: item %>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

It works fine to populate and render the partial, but i can't suss out how to pass to the partial the view_path so that it is dynamically replace the temporary # with <%= the_right_path =>.

I  tried to do:

```
<%= render partial: 'application/item_synopsis_builder', locals: {item: item, path: game_path } %>
```

But I just get an error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"games"}
```

But if I render the partial with href="#", it renders fine.

I also tried my luck with `href="<%= "#{item}_path" %>"` but it just print out the ref of the object item.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know is this is your error, but it seems to me that `game_path` expects a game object as argument, that might be your error.

EDIT:

```
<% @games.each do |item| %>
  <section> 
    <%= render partial: 'application/item_synopsis_builder', locals:{item: item, path: game_path(item) %>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Isn't game_path available from the Game view/controller/whatever i'm in?

Comment: Yes, it is. But `game_path` is the path to a particular game (used for show, update, destroy), so it needs a game object to retrieve the id from. If you want to link to the index page, use `games_path` (notice the 's').

Comment: No I do want to render the path to the individual game. I'm building a listing of games and need to link to their respective pages.

Answer (score 1):

If the URLs you're looking for are named after the models, you can simply do:

```
<%= link_to "Read more", item %>
```

This will automatically generate `game_path` or `promotion_path` for you, depending on the item.

The method that does all this magic is called [`polymorphic_url`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L58).

The reason why your current example doesn't work is because you didn't give the object to `game_path`. Now it doesn't know which ID to generate. There is no route that matches `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"games"}`, but there is a route that matches `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"games", :id=>"something"}`.

Comment: That does work fine with the link_to helper. Then i have a stoopid question. is it possible to wrap a tag with the link_to helper?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `<%= link_to content_tag(:div, "foo"), item %>` ? If you need to have automatic url generation outside `link_to` and `form_for`, you can use `url_for`.

Comment: Yop i was looking for something like that. I just tried  <%= link_to(item) do %> 
  <%= image_tag item.thumbnail %>
  <% end -%>
and it worked fine. Thanks for the url_for tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You can send it as a string and then call it with send

something like this:

```
render partial: 'partial', locals: { link: "products_path" }
```

on the partial:

```
send(link, variable: 'hello', other: 'world')
```